# Запрет window.opener из открытой вкладки/окна

Tags: javascript

Есть ссылки с разными доменами (чужими). Некоторые сайты через `window.opener.location.href` заменяют наш сайт.

Как можно запретить управление `window.opener`?
Ссылки с `target="_blank"`, но есть и `window.open()`

Пробовал способ (не сработало):

```
var w = window.open(url);
w.opener = null;
```